# How to extend object with Lo-Dash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, extend, lodash

I have trouble merging two objects using [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) and don't understand why below code doesn't work. I would expect `_merge` call to extend `bbb` with `fnaaa`, this doesn't happen however.

```
my={};
my.aaa=function() {}
my.aaa.prototype.fnaaa=function() {}

bbb={fnbbb:function() {}}
_.merge(bbb,new my.aaa());
```

jQuery $.extend does work and if I run code below it extends bbb as expected:

```
my={};
my.aaa=function() {}
my.aaa.prototype.fnaaa=function() {}

bbb={fnbbb:function() {}}
$.extend(bbb,new my.aaa());
```

Why is it happening and how to do the same with Lo-Dash?

EDIT: is it because fnaaa is not enumerable? If so how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Lo-Dash's **_.merge** only copies enumerable properties of objects. By definition enumerable properties do not include prototypes.

The reason for this behavior could be explained as if you called **_.keys** on an object, you likely wouldn't want the prototype methods showing up in the response.

> > https://lodash.com/docs#merge
> >
> > "Recursively merges own enumerable properties of the source object(s),
> >     that..."

jQuery's **$.extend** will actually copy the object and the prototype:

> > http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/
> >
> > "However, properties inherited from the object's prototype will be copied over.. "

I would sum it up to the fact that Lo-Dash is meant to be light weight and jQuery is meant to be more feature rich. I know this doesn't answer the 'how?' but it maybe it answers the 'why?'.

For brevity here's a little more about enumerable properties:
http://www.2ality.com/2011/07/js-properties.html